# Multiple 301 redirects, do search engines / user-agents see them all?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, server, 301-redirect

I've put in place a lot of different 301 redirects to deal with numerous URL changes.

And for certain URLs there are 3-4 different 301 redirects landing the visitors to the new URL.

I heard that 301 loses pagerank/linkjuice. All the 301's are onsite for the same domain. With a mix of PHP 301's and htaccess 301's.

So for instance:

```
articles/news.php?id=2 ---> articles/blog.php?id=2  [filename change]
articles/* ---> /*                                  [subdir to root]
/blog.php?id=2 ---> /title-of-post                  [mod rewrite url change]
```

So if you were to visit `/articles/news.php?id=2` there will be two 301 redirects until you land on the `/yellow-wellington-boots/`.

My question is does Google see the intermediate redirects, or just the final page the 301's redirect to?

Comment: Any reason you can't skip all of the middle redirects?

Answer (score 3):

The crawler will probably "see" the intermediate URLs insofar as going there and then being redirected again, but it won't actually care about or store/index them, as that's the entire point of the 301: you're telling it that URL is no longer valid and to go look elsewhere.

Last June, Matt Cutts did a [video with SEOMoz](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/whiteboard-interview-googles-matt-cutts-on-redirects-trust-more) where redirect chains were specifically brought up ~10:00, summarized as:

> Matt was very clear that Google can and usually will deal with one or two redirects in a series, but three is pushing it and anything beyond that probably won't be followed.

...though elsewhere he's quoted as [saying at a PubCon](http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4064810.htm) that Google would follow up to ten of them. (I wouldn't try and find out.) And here's [another post](http://helpmyseo.com/seo-tips/300-do-301-redirect-chains-hurt-your-seo.html) that mentions Bing–now also powering Yahoo–have at some point said they don't like it, either.

All that said, you should ultimately work toward getting rid of the intermediate steps altogether.